# Display the data in <div> into popup using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#popup_div").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });

        $("#btn_click").click(function() {
            $("#popup_div").dialog("open");
            //$("#popup_div").toggle("100", $("#popup_div").dialog("close"));
        });
    });

</script>
```

I wrote a function which will display the data in popup and immediately the popup will close. I need that popup stays sometime after clicking close button it will close.

Comment: can you make fiddle of the same ???

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$("#btn_click").click(function () {
    $("#popup_div").dialog("open");
});
// code to close the dialog, let btnClose is the Id of button in popup_div
$("#popup_div").on('click','#btnClose',function(){
     $("#popup_div").dialog("close");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/qb5w0f9g/)

Comment: still popup was automatically closed

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dialog to delay before closing then set a timeout:

```
   $("#popup_div").on('click', '#btnClose', function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#popup_div").dialog("close");
        }, 1000);
    });
```

JSFiddle example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/606pgg4o/1/**